# Why is this HTTP stream causing my app to get rejected?

Tags: iphone, ios, streaming

I have an app that uses NASA live TV stream for the iphone/ipad which they use in their own app, but my app got rejected because:

> 2.2     Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected

Referring to the stream: http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/nasatv/NTV-Public-IPS.m3u8

```
EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=298577
http://liveips.nasa.gov.edgesuite.net/ksc/Edge.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=298577
http://liveips.nasa.gov.edgesuite.net/msfc/Edge.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=532383
http://liveips.nasa.gov.edgesuite.net/ksc/3G.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=532383
http://liveips.nasa.gov.edgesuite.net/msfc/3G.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=838577
http://liveips.nasa.gov.edgesuite.net/ksc/Wifi.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=838577
http://liveips.nasa.gov.edgesuite.net/msfc/Wifi.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=32000
http://liveips.nasa.gov.edgesuite.net/ksc/Edgeaudio.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=32000
http://liveips.nasa.gov.edgesuite.net/msfc/Edgeaudio.m3u8
```

> When we accessed
>   "http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/nasatv/NTV-Public-IPS.m3u8",
>   we did not find a 64kbps stream...
>   verify that the stream advertises and
>   measures 64kbps or less

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need 64kbps stream if you are going to allow user to watch live streaming on a cellular network, you can use [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) demo to determine current network status (cellular or wifi) and block user from watching live stream on a cellular network.

See technical note [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2224/_index.html) (TN2224) for more information about HTTP Live Streaming requirements. And you may need to try [HTTP Live Streaming Tools](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wo/5.1.17.2.1.3.3.1.0.1.1.0.3.8.3.3.1) on your stream to see what is wrong.

I get a lot of errors from the following command.

```
$mediastreamvalidator validate http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/nasatv/NTV-Public-IPS.m3u8
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply. They said it needs 64kbps or less, the Edgeaudio.m3u8 bandwidth is 32kbps so would that not suffice? As for the warnings theres not much i can do about that as NASA control the stream, my main issue is other apps seem to use the stream ok (i.e on the app store)

Comment: My app was rejected many times by the stream issue, seems there are something not described in TN: the master playlist must be ordered by bandwidth (low to high) so Edgeaudio.m3u8 must be the first entry.

Comment: You can't say "Another app is approved, why not mine?" My app version 1.1 is rejected because some feature in version 1.0 (in AppStore) is not approved, it's all about your luck which staff will review your app.